# Kable conditional coloring using row_spec

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to color cells in each row based on a condition using `kable`. I saw a few examples of column_spec and cell_spec because it's still a bit manual since I'm interested in conditional coloring by row. Here's an example of column_spec, and wondering if this can be down with row_spec or similar that's more efficient than column_spec or cell_spec?

```
mtcars[1:8, 1:8] %>%
      arrange(wt) %>%
      kbl(booktabs = T, linesep = "") %>% 
      kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
      column_spec(6, color = "white", background = ifelse(mtcars[1:8,1:8]$drat > 3, "red", "green"))
```

[image]

However, the conditional formatting I'm interested in is coloring, say Mazda RX4 row has any values >10 then red. This is just example data so context isn't relevant here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use some `dplyr` operations before piping into `Kable`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knit)
library(kableExtra)

mtcars_kbl <- mtcars[1:8, 1:8] 

mtcars_kbl$car = row.names(mtcars_kbl)
row.names(mtcars_kbl) <- NULL

mtcars_kbl %>% arrange(wt) %>% 
  relocate(car) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(1:8, 
           ~ cell_spec(.x, 
                       color = ifelse(car == "Mazda RX4" & .x > 10, "white", "black"), 
                       background = ifelse(car == "Mazda RX4" & .x > 10, "red", "white")
                       )
           )
    ) %>% 
  kable(booktabs = T, linesep = "", format = "html", escape = F) %>% 
  kable_paper(full_width = F)
```

[image: kable_cell_spec]